# Configuring QoS on Cisco ASA 5525-X

Tags: cisco, qos

I'm trying to configure QoS on a Cisco 5525-X ASA and feel like I'm beginning to get a handle on it but the queue-limit and tx-ring-limit calculations are losing me.

What I've got right now is a 100Mbps connection shared between video conferencing and internet traffic.  I want to put the video traffic into a low latency queue to ensure it runs smoothly.  From what I understand I'll need to create an ACL to catch all video conferencing traffic and apply that to a service policy.  The documentation isn't making a few points clear, however.

In a hierarchical priority queue, is the queue-limit to be calculated based on the entire 100Mbps bandwidth, or just the amount I want to dedicate to video traffic?  I don't want video traffic to take up the ENTIRE bandwidth.

With traffic shaping enabled, I plan to set the traffic shape to the full 100Mbps connection.  From what I understand this should buffer any packets that would exceed the bandwidth rather than drop them.

I'm running my calculations off of tables 19-1 and 19-2 in http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa92/configuration/firewall/asa-firewall-cli/conns-qos.html#75446

Comment: Anything below the 5550 and the 5500-X series only supports policing and not shaping so you won't be able to buffer the packets http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/82310-qos-voip-vpn.html#anc6